# Returning an alternate column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A is an experimental dataframe which contains a list of things which have been used (along with date etc). Dataframe B is a reference dataframe. Dataframe A and B have matching index numbers. I want to update Dataframe A with extra information from Dataframe B, where the index numbers match.

For example

dfA

```
REF
ABC
DEF
DEF
XYZ
```

dfB

```
REF VALUE
ABC 1.23
DEF 2.22
XYZ 3.33
```

In reality the reference dataframe is much larger than the experimental dataframe. I would like to create a new column in dataframe A with the value from dataframe B based on matching references. I have tried 'is in' and where but the mis matched lengths of the series creating an error. 
I have tried using merge but as dataframe A has repetitions of the reference value the merged dataframe has too many rows. 
Is there an effective way to do this without creating a new series or column for each reference?

Answer (score 1):

Using **`map`** with **`set_index`**

```
df1['res'] = df1.REF.map(df2.set_index('REF')['VALUE'])

   REF   res
0  ABC  1.23
1  DEF  2.22
2  DEF  2.22
3  XYZ  3.33
```

Comment: Thank you, turns out I had some duplicate data in my reference frame which was causing some funny results, your code really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `join`

Assuming your indexes are `REF` in both dataframes, you can simply do

`dfA.join(dfB)`

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame(['ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'XYZ'], columns=['REF'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame([['ABC', 1.23], ['DEF', 2.22], ['XYZ', 3.33]], columns=['REF', 'VALUE'])

dfA = dfA.set_index('REF')
dfB = dfB.set_index('REF')

dfA.join(dfB)
```

Comment: Thank you, turns out I had some duplicate data in my reference frame which was causing some funny results, your code really helped.